# Laravel - What is the opposite of the save method on a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Let's say I'm making an association on a one-to-many relationship, like this

```
$artwork->views()->save($view);
```

How would I go about removing this association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`detach()` is for many-to-many relationships, what you want is `dissociate()`. As per the docs:

```
$user->account()->dissociate();
$user->save();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: I think this is correct, however, how do I remove only one associated item?

Comment: Good question. Can't try myself at the moment, but maybe try going from the other model and dissociating, see if that works?

Comment: I went the long way around, and ended up setting the other model to have an artwork_id of NULL, which effectively does the same thing. This is the correct answer. Thanks @Joel Hinz

Answer (score 0):

You're showing a code which creates an association. I guess you mean deleting then:

```
App\Views::destroy(245);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#deleting-models

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Joel Hinz's answer, to remove only one item from the relationship how about this:

```php
$artwork->views()->first()->delete();
```

Alternatively you can use a `where` to select, or `latest` etc.